# Is there a way to break a CHECK line into multiple lines in llvm-lit?

Tags: llvm, llvm-lit

Imagine the following test line. Its a negative test by the way.

```
# CHECK: :[[@LINE+1]]:1: error: Some extremely long error messeage which goes way beyond 80 character long so would be nice to break it up
add r1, r2, r3, r4
```

What I want is to break it up to make it more readable like

```
# CHECK: :[[@LINE+1]]:1: error: Some extremely long error messeage which\
# CHECK: goes way beyond 80 character long so would be nice to break it up
add r1, r2, r3, r4
```

The line breaking with `\` is working with `# RUN` command, but here it is not. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. There is a directive ([source](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/FileCheck.html)) `CHECK-SAME` which does what I need. I wanted to update the question to mention it is exist, but not works. Turned out the problem was that I forget to change the `[[@LINE+1]]` to `[[@LINE+2]]` since now the actual assembly instruction is 2 lines away from that line. The working solution

```
# CHECK: :[[@LINE+2]]:1: error: Some extremely long error messeage which 
# CHECK-SAME: goes way beyond 80 character long so would be nice to break it up
add r1, r2, r3, r4
```